# How to make a jquery Image with Text rotator?

Tags: jquery, css, image, wordpress, image-rotation

How can I make an image and text rotator where I can modify with css the position and appearance of the text field and boder size for the picture. Nothing fancy, just an array of images and text that change every x seconds.

Here's an example. In the header area you can see a red block and the picture on the right.

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine. Go ask on the Workpress site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Forget wordpress, it can be any script, for example jquery.

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking code-related questions, not for shopping for scripts.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a open source code, or template.

Comment: @Diodeus Neither is WordPress Stack Exchange. Do not recommend that site for shopping questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/

or

http://www.sequencejs.com/

are js sliders I know of that basically just animate the slides, which can contain all the divs/images styled via normal CSS within it.

Comment: Thanks the Parallax example looks great.